# How to combine bash parameter expansion and command substitution?

Tags: bash

I want to add a path to my `PATH` variable which includes the lowercase name of the OS. I can do the following now:

```sh
osname=$(uname -s)
osname=${osname,,}
export PATH="${HOME}/this/that/${osname}/bin"
```

Is there a way to write this on a single line, avoiding the variable itself?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to embed an execution in your PATH if you can avoid it.

```
declare -l osname="$(uname -s)" && export PATH="${HOME}/this/that/${osname}/bin";
```

Comment: Though it shouldn't be an issue to parse once at assign time.

Comment: Command substitution works fine in string concatenation, you don't need two commands

Comment: Is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way

```
export PATH=$PATH:${HOME}/this/that/$(uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/bin
```

I added $PATH at the beginning of the value since I guess you don't want to loose your actual $PATH